# Don't load window if an exception is thrown in the Window's constructor

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to open a new window at the click of a button

```
private void ReportsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReportsWindow reports = new ReportsWindow();
    reports.ShowDialog();
}
```

I'm trying to make it so, in the constructor, a function loads items from an XML file.  If for any reason the load fails, the constructor catches the exception and displays a messagebox and does not open the window.

```
private List<ReportXmlItem> items;

public ReportsWindow()
{
    try
    {
        LoadXmlList();
        InitializeComponent();
        reportsListBox.ItemsSource = items;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Reports file not found. Locate file from settings menu.");
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

However I get the following exception thrown from the ShowDialog:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed.'

If I remove `this.Close()` then a blank Window is opened.  I was under the impression that because `InitializeComponent()` is not called no window should be created.

How should I change this so if the XML file cannot be loaded/fails (from `LoadXmlList()`), the window doesn't needlessly get created and just displays the MessageBox and returns focus to the previous window.

All my XML file related code is contained in the ReportsWindow class, so I would like to avoid using it elsewhere if that is possible.

Comment: You can't close it in the constructor because it hasn't opened yet. However, it is *on track* to open. `Loaded += (s, e) => Close();` isn't great; it'll be momentarily visible. Let me find a better event.

Comment: Use the constructor to create the object, you're asking for trouble trying to do all this other stuff there. Move it to the Loaded event, or else do it before you create the window (that way, if it fails, like you are wanting to do, you avoid creating the window). Really, from a architectural standpoint, why do you want all that business logic in your window class?

Comment: How about calling the making items as Property in ReportsWindow. Then in the button click first check for it (which calls the LoadXmlList() ...lazy load) and handle it appropriately.

Comment: Before calling `reports.ShowDialog();` change your `LoadXmlList();` to return a boolean if successful and set a property in that class. Then when you construct this class check this property, if false then don't call `reports.ShowDialog();`... Also here's a quick list of order of events that may be useful [here](https://wpf.2000things.com/2012/07/30/613-window-event-sequence/) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37975171/1797425) maybe useful as well.\

Comment: Put the try-catch around the code in `ReportsButton_Click`, not in the constructor. Also, you may want to be more specific in your exception catching; getting "some error" does not guarantee that the thing going wrong is that the reports file could not be found.

Comment: I have been a bit stupid here in thinking the Window is shown when InitializeComponent is called (even though I have actually used ShowDialog).  I will make LoadXmlList a public method and call it in the Button Click. ...And I have all my business logic in my window class because I'm struggling to get my head around MVVM - I will have another go at it once I get better at the basics.

Comment: FWIW. You should definitely learn MVVM if you plan on using wpf for anything substantial. You should also avoid substantial code in a ctor. Especially any code likely to error. Doubly true if you were planning on showing some messagebox or something when handling that error. Your ctor goes bang = no view.

Answer (score -1):

You need something like next Code:

```
private void ReportsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    try{
        ReportsWindow reports = new ReportsWindow();
        reports.ShowDialog();
    }
    //if we need manage that error only, we catch that exception type only ;)
    //if you want manage all exceptions you'll need specify Exception type
    catch(ReportsFileNotFoundException ex){
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

You can't call the close method in the constuctor, because the window wasn't shown yet.

```
private List<ReportXmlItem> items;

public ReportsWindow(){
    LoadXmlList();
    InitializeComponent();
    reportsListBox.ItemsSource = items;
}

void LoadXmlList(){
    //we throw the custom exception if we couldn't load the files
    throw new ReportsFileNotFoundException("Reports file not found. Locate file from settings menu.");
}
```

Comment: And `ReportsFileNotFoundException` does what exactly? Also IMHO, you shouldn't be throwing an exception you can't handle as well.